# Using IAM to connect to AWS s3 without credentials in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS. I am trying to connect to AmazonS3 using IAM role. I am not using secret keys here. Changes have been done at AWS side regarding IAM.

I have to **create AmazonS3 client object**. I tried to create object by following code:

```
        public AmazonS3 AmazonS3Provider() {
            AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        }
```

But it is returning :

```
"status":500,"exception":"AmazonS3Exception","message":"Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Next, I tried to connect AWS s3 using AWSSecretsManagerClient using the following code:

```
public AmazonS3 AmazonS3Provider() {        
    return (AmazonS3) AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.defaultClient();
}
```

But it was throwing error that `AWSSecretsManagerClient object cannot be cast to AmazonS3`.

Also, I tried to build client object using the following code:

```
AWSCredentials credentials;
    try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file.", e);
    }
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(s3EndPoint)
            .build();
```

But is throwing AmazonClientException.

Can someone guide me how to build client object using IAM role.

Comment: The code provided in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AuthUsingTempSessionToken.html) works for me perfectly. Did you try this?

Comment: Are you using an EC2 instance?

Comment: @ShubhamDhingra how to get the values of roleARN and roleSessionName

Comment: You can get the role ARN from the page where you made the IAM Role to allow S3 access and you can give any session name.

Comment: @AlbertMarrero yes using EC2 instance

Comment: Is there an AWS profile attached to that ec2 instance?

Comment: In environment variable, aws credential path is given @AlbertMarrero

Comment: Use an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) to pass an IAM role to an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM access key and secret key (AWS credential) path locations are stored in environment variable. I was able to create client object using WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider with the following code:

```
        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.create())
            .withRegion("Region-name")
            .build();
```